# Getting error while fetch the page of ADFS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, saml, adfs2.0

I have installed the ADFS 2.0 on windows server 8, When I am going to fetch the page (FormsSignIn.aspx) which is under adfs/ls dierctory I am getting below error

`There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.`

I have checked the logs in event viewer and got the below message

`Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageException: MSIS7015: This request does not contain the expected protocol message or incorrect protocol parameters were found according to the HTTP SAML protocol bindings.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveContext.EnsureCurrent(HttpContext context)`

I have checked all the possible way but not able to reslove this problem.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to utilize Forms authentication in ADFS, you do not access this page directly, rather you [configure the ADFS web.config for forms authn](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx) and you [claims enable your application / service provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx) (SP).  The methods for claims enabling an application can vary depending on the version of Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) used.